# pagination shows all the result , despite using paginator helper and pagination Cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, controller, pagination, paginator

So i am new to **Cakephp 3.x** , and i am trying to paginate a set of data , but the problem is all the entries are being displayed , also the navigation bar in the bottom is showing, and i guess it's working fine.

Below is my controller.

```
public $paginate = ['limit' => 2,'order' => ['sample.posts' => 'asc']];

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->layout = 'frontend';
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
}

public function index()
{
    $this->set('Posts', $this->paginate());
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

And this is my template file.

```
<table>
        <tr>paginate
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ID', 'id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Title', 'title'); ?></th>
        </tr>
           <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post['id'] ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $post['title'] ?> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>  
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>   
<?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(); ?>
```

any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your index function should have a paginate function and you should give $posts as a parameter to it.

```
       public function index()
       {
           $posts = $this->Posts->find('all');
           $posts = $this->paginate($posts);
           $this->set(compact('posts'));
       }
```